# click only letter and play audio doesn't work on Mac

Tags: javascript, css, audio

I have a problem.
When my project run on Mac at browsers (Firefox, Chrome) and I make click on letter, it's doesn't work. Namely, It does not show me the underline when I click on the letter and it does not play audio.
Also, I open console and I don't show a problem.
Can you help me please?

```js
var audioletter = document.getElementById("audiolettersound");
// Original String
var letterstring = "Nikos nikos string";
// Replace string
letterstring=letterstring.replace(/(n)/gi,'<span class="Char" onclick="PlayDing();">$1</span>');
//Insert String
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=letterstring;
// Audio Function
function PlayDing(){
audioletter.play();
}
```

```css
.Char:Hover{text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<audio id="audiolettersound">
<source src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```

Comment: Have you actually separated any of your javascript and css?

You're missing script tags for your js code and then you throw in some css causing a syntax error that should be clearly visible in the browser console and indeed if you run the code snipper above it tells you there's an error

Comment: first fix your snippet to actually work. If you move the CSS to the CSS and the HTML to the HTML it actually works

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Sagar V, It doesn't show me in console.